# Update/Remove Many to Many Field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have saved the object in the database with the many to many fields, after saving the object in the database I want to append one more ID in the many to many field so how can I do that in Django.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    account = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

JSON from Frontend

```
{
  "name": "Project 1",
  "description": "description of project 1",
  "account": [1, 2] 
}
```

assume the object is saved now, what if I want to add id 3 to the account or remove id 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Project.objects.get(id=1)
u = User.objects.get(id=234)
u.project_set.add(p) #add
u.project_set.remove(p) #remove
```

Note that you can also to `p.account.add()` or `p.account.remove()`.

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference